# Reference lstlisting code by caption/title instead of number

Tags: cross-referencing, lstlisting

In my LaTeX document I use `\ref{code.java}` to reference a code as shown in the image below and it shows the section/chapter number. Why it shows "1" instead of `code.java`? Is it possible to make the code name appear instead of the number of section/chapter?

[image]

This is my LaTeX code using `lstlisting` and setting a label name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{verde}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35}
\definecolor{jpurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle=\color{jpurple}\bfseries,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{verde},
  morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{/**}{*/},
  extendedchars=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  breaklines=true,
  backgroundcolor=\color{cyan!10},
  breakautoindent=true,
  captionpos=b,
  xleftmargin=0pt,
  tabsize=4
}

\title{example}
\author{marcellocamara}
\date{March 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Let's cite the code \ref{code.java} as example.

\begin{lstlisting}[title = {code.java}, label={code.java}]
public class MyClassName {

    Some java code.

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please share the complete code starting with `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's more than 3500 lines... I can edit and post an example with that I want. It will help ? the problem is already writed. I just need to change the reference to lib lstlisting

Comment: Yes a minimal working example is required.

Comment: I shared the simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ref` references listings by its automatically assigned number. Usually a caption is assigned to listings with the `caption={My caption}` option which makes the caption look like

> Listing 1: My caption

As you are using the `title` option, the numbering is suppressed from being output and instead the literal title is shown.

One option to reference the caption is to use the `\nameref` command from the `nameref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}

\definecolor{verde}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35}
\definecolor{jpurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ ... }

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Let's cite the code \nameref{code.java} as example.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={code.java (caption)}, title={code.java (title)}, label={code.java}]
public class MyClassName {

    Some java code.

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `\nameref` uses the provided `caption` for the reference, not the `title`. So if you want both to be the same, you have to duplicate the text for `caption` and `title`.

Comment: That's worked perfectly.